# Python/Django circular dependency with models.py (NOT in ForeignKey.etc)

Tags: python, django

I have x `models.py` files, in x different Django apps. I have certain queries related to said models thatI call throughout my app. I figured the best way to DRY-ify this is to have the query be called by a method inside the model.

These query methods actually query /other/ models inside /other/ apps (and therefore other `models.py` files). I understand that this increases coupling, but it's a large and highly specialised project, so I can't really write generic reusable apps for a lot of the stuff.

For example:

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_future_shifts(self):
        return Shift.objects.filter(mentor = self, session__date__gt = timezone.now())
```

I've ended up with a circular dependency (it spans along 4 apps so I figured it was too long to post ALL that code here unless absolutely necessary).

The usual circular dependency advice for Django models on SO is related to `models.ForeignKey` and that is not my issue. I need to actually *access* the 'foreign' model.

I'm told that a circular dependency is a sign of bad design, and my bad design is that I have too many dynamic helper methods in my models? Django doesn't really provide anywhere else to put these without adhering to DRY.

Comment: If you want to import `Shift` in `Mentor` class, import it within a method rather than top of models.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a method, `django.db.models.get_model()`, that gets a model given its name. This'll fix it as you aren't actually importing the model.

Comment: Specifically *you* don't need to import the model, but Django will automagically import it for you (and return a reference to the model) when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_future_shifts()` method implies that `Shift` has a FK on `Mentor`. In this case, you don't need to import `Shift` in the module containing `Mentor`, you can just use the reverse relationship ie:

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_future_shifts(self):
        return self.shift_set.filter(session__date__gt=timezone.now())
```

but this will only "technically" solve the circular dependency, since it means that `Mentor` has some direct knowledge of another app that itself depends on the app where `Mentor` is defined and the whole thing will break if you remove this other app from your settings.

Another solution is to define `get_future_shifts` in the same app as `Shift' and monkeypatch`Mentor`, ie:

```
from otherapp.models import Mentor

class Shift(models.Model):
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(Mentor)

# Extend Mentor with get_future_shifts helper    
def get_future_shifts(mentor):
    return mentor.shift_set.filter(session__date__gt=timezone.now())

Mentor.get_future_shifts = get_future_shifts
```

Some will frown upon extending a class from another module / app, but just defining a FK on Mentor here is already extending `Mentor`, so at least we keep related stuff together and now `Mentor` has no direct dependency on `Shift` - as long as nothing in `Mentor`'s app's views etc depends on `get_future_shifts()` at least, but then it means that `Shifts` should really belong to the same app as `Mentor`.